# How to make the openpose use caffe without cuda supported

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, caffe, video-processing, openpose

I wan to try Openpose:

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose

in my laptop with an AMD video card,so no cuda is possible,

is that possiable?How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running caffe with non-NVIDIA card requires opencl branch. Integrating that branch with the caffe branch used by `OpenPose` might be tricky (and might be straight forward - I haven't tried it myself).
If you want to "play it safe", you can disable ALL GPU support by setting

```
CPU_ONLY := 1
```

In your `Makefile.config` before compiling caffe.
This way you'll have a CPU version that does not require any CUDA/NVIDIA support.

Comment: To clarify, this `Makefile.config` is within Caffe, not OpenPose?

Comment: @Shai, is this the same for an Nvidia graphics card with 2.1 compute capability?  Ie. lower than minimum of 3.0 required for CuDNN.

Comment: @mLstudent33 this setting will ignore any GPU code and compile only the CPU part

Comment: @Shai thanks for the reply!  I was dreaming of something like this for a tennis coaching app idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would add to [Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44227061/1714410) that you need to disable

```
# USE_CUDNN := 1
```

sometime when its left on,the setup function of layers do some CUDA ASSERT  checking that fails and prevent the program to continue

Answer (score 0):

<s>There is no way not to use CUDA with OpenPose at the moment. OpenPose internally uses CUDA code for rendering, for cubic resize and for non-maximum suppression. In the future, it is intended to move the CUDA code to OpenCL (so it can work on any graphics card), but that is a long-term goal.</s>

EDITED: OpenPose added CPU-only and even OpenCL support a few months back, you can check their [installation documentation](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md).

Comment: has this been done yet?  I am getting conflicting info on the web.

Comment: Yes, it was about a year ago (this message was way older than that). Updated the answer! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the latest cpu version(Latest openpose module, newest upgrade). There's no such cuda tech needed, so nothing much to bother about whether graphics card is nvidia or else.